# Rails two nested attributes, "comments" on "posts" and on "issues" Not Saving Rollback

Tags: nested, ruby-on-rails-5, rollback

This is the controller code that fails to save.

```
     def create
        if params[:post_id]
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
            @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
        elsif params[:issue_id]
            @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
            @comment = @issue.comments.new(comment_params)
        end
        if @comment.save
            if @comment.issue_id
                redirect_to Issue.find(@comment.issue_id)
            elsif @comment.post_id
                redirect_to Post.find(@comment.post_id)
            end
        else
            redirect_to edit_username_path(current_user)
        end
    end
    ...
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
```

And then here's the comment form:

```
      <%= simple_form_for [@issue, @issue.comments.build] do |f| %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= f.input :content, required: true, input_html: { class: 'textarea', id: 'issuecommentnew' } %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Create New Comment" %>
      <% end %>
```

if I move it around I can get it to redirect back to the issue, but no comments are saved.

Here's the params output:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gNiPWM8IMa25LC0qKZ1WPnGbW4rnRCXXZficHoSM/b+t4jdcNVPS3xn4/PGjam/QiJPdMjluilIw32E2KafXJQ==", "comment"=><ActionController::Parameters {"content"=>"hello"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Create New Comment", "controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"create", "issue_id"=>"1"}
```

And the comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :issue

    after_commit :create_notifications, on: :create

    private

    def create_notifications
        Notification.create do |notification|
            notification.notify_type = "post"
            notification.actor = self.user
            notification.user = self.post.user
            notification.target = self
            notification.second_target = self.post
        end
    end

end
```

And in the schema:

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.string "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "issue_id"
  end
```

I've included:

`comment_params.merge(user: current_user, post: 0)` and `issue: 0`

And

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Post must exist, User must exist:`

went to

`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Post(#70348245809340) expected, got 0 which is an instance of`

solved:

`issue: Issue.new`

Comment: I bet this is failing on an association validation. Try changing `@comment.save` to `@comment.save!` and see if you get a useful exception

Comment: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Post must exist, User must exist:` but I saved with the Issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing an associated `post` and `user`. You'll have to either make sure both exist, and pass in a valid `post_id` and `user_id`, or do:

`belongs_to :post, optional: true`
`belongs_to :user, optional: true`

You're currently merging an id of 0 for both, which could never belong to a valid record of either type.